# File compressed with both gzip and compress UNIX

Tags: unix, compression

I have a file compressed with gzip first and then zip.

Let's say the extension is `file_name.gz.zip`. Looking at the file name (compressed) I can certainly use the commands to decompress them as below:

```
uncompress -p compressed_file_name | gunzip
```

Is there a way to determine how many times the file has been compressed and with which utilities provided the file name does not contain the correct extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the first few bytes.  If they indicate a .gz, .zip, or some other file type, then try decompressing.  If that works, then look at the first few bytes of the result and repeat.

See this [list of file signatures](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).  `1F 8B 08` is gzip.  `50 4B 03 04` is zip.